# Undefined control sequence: rowcolors, with newer beamer

Tags: beamer, color, compilation-error

I tried to recompile a LaTeX source that compiled seamlessly last week but that time it failed with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \rowcolors
```

I made a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \rowcolors[]{1}{blue!20}{green!40}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    column 1& column 2\\
    value 1 & value 2\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The only thing that changes is that I updated my box (Debian testing) a few days ago.

I can still compile that file for instance with beamer v3.57 but it now fails with beamer v3.65. If I remove the beamer class and just try to compile the file as an article (by adding a `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`), it succeeds.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how I could fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Compiles without problem here using updated miktex.

Comment: Also fine with TeXLive 2021, updated. Using beamer 3.66. Check your log, does it actually load `colortbl.sty`

Comment: Please post your `.log` file

Comment: you probably got the version where the loading order was broken (https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/759). Try with `\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}` before the class

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : indeed, that solves it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz indeed, I didn't see that one, thanks.